# (How) can I avoid undesired effects of booting with "nomodeset"?

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, hibernate, nomodeset

Sometimes (approximately 1 of 3 times) waking from hibernation with Ubuntu 14.04 on my HP pavilion dv6000 laptop computer ends with a black screen with backlight and the mouse pointer - in those cases, I must reset the computer. Therefore, I followed the advice from the following URL:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelHibernate#Dead.2C_blank.2C_or_black_screen_on_resume

> One thing to try is disabling Kernel Mode Setting. One may do this by editing the grub configuration:
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/default/grub
> ```
>
> Find the line reading:
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
> ```
>
> Add nomodeset to the end, inside the quotes:
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
> ```

Unfortunately after that, my screen resolution is coarser than usually and the keyboard layout mapping is incorrect. How can I correct this?